# Make file in C giving fatal error

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile in C but i am facing some issues.
I have my main .c, one .c which keeps the functions implementations and one .h which keeps the functions declarations.
When i try to run the makefile, i get a fatal error.
here is my makefile:

```
INCL   = prog.h
SRC    = prog.c prog_fun.c
OBJ    = $(SRC:.c=.o)
EXE    = prog


CC = gcc  
CFLAGS  = -c
RM      = rm -rf

all: prog

prog: prog.o prog_fun.o
    gcc -o prog prog.o prog_fun.o 

prog.o: prog.c 
    gcc -c prog.c

prog_fun.o: prog_fun.c prog.h
    gcc -c prog.c

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(EXE)
```

The error i get is this:

```
gcc -c prog.c
prog.c:11:19: fatal error: prog.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'prog.o' failed
make: *** [prog.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: This is very unclear. You're mentioning files that does not exist in your Makefile, and your Makefile refers to files you do not mention.

Comment: Where is the header file, and what is its name? What happens when you try to build the executable on the command line? (In general, you can't do something with Make unless you know how to do it *without* Make.)

Comment: The header file is in the same location as the other .c files. the name for it is prog.h. When i try to run without make the program is compiled and run properly

Comment: Did you include the header using `#include <prog.h>` or `#include "prog.h"`?  For the former, you'd need `-I.` on the `gcc` command-line.  Also: why does your recipe for `prog_fun.o` compile `prog.c`?  shouldn't that be `prog_fun.c`?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do by using this

`prog_fun.o: prog_fun.c header.h`

It should be only

```
prog_fun.o: prog_fun.c
```

Modify your make file as

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~$ vi makefile 
INCL   = header.h
SRC    = prog.c prog_fun.c
OBJ    = $(SRC:.c=.o)
EXE    = prog


CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -c
RM      = rm -rf

all: prog
prog: prog.o prog_fun.o
        gcc -o prog prog.o prog_fun.o 
prog.o: prog.c
        gcc -c prog.c header.h
prog_fun.o: prog_fun.c
        gcc -c prog_fun.c header.h

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ) $(EXE)
```

next run it

```
xxyz@xyz-PC:~$ make
gcc -c prog.c header.h
gcc -c prog_fun.c header.h
gcc -o prog prog.o prog_fun.o
```

I hope it will work now and make sure indention is correct(not manual spaces, it should be tab key)

Comment: thank you for your help,but still, i get a very similar error: :(                   gcc -c prog.c prog.h
gcc: error: prog.h: No such file or directory
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'prog.o' failed
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

Comment: change `prog.h` to some other name like `header.h`. because `make` is confusing while choosing `prog.h` & `prog.o` as in both before `dot` name are same. Replace `prog.h` with `header.h` where ever you are using previously, it works.

Comment: @user9091498 are you getting ?